# Why disable xntpd slew?

Tags: aix, ntp

Until Dec 31, we have to set:

```
chssys -s xntpd -a "-x"
```

**Question:** but why disable it in January? Why could it cause problems if we leave the "-x"?

Comment: Curious where that recommendation came from

Comment: applications may have issues with it (if its not set..), at least our "inside" communication says..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because it can interfere with daylight saving.

Comment: ntp has no idea about daylight saving. The other answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The last minute of 2016 (as counted in the UTC time zone) will have 61 seconds, so that in the UTC time zone the last second of 2016 will be 23:59:60. See [Leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) on Wikipedia.

The system call `time()` *does not count* leap seconds (this is a POSIX requirement), and thus for applications which base their date and time calculations on `time()` there will be one second which will be counted twice, *unless* the system disregards the leap second and instead of making a step adjustment makes tiny little adjustments over the next few hours or days.

Poorly written (or simply way too old) applications may misbehave when confronted with 61 seconds long minutes. The [option `-x`](https://community.hpe.com/t5/General/HP-Support-Statement-for-XNTPD-Leap-Second-Processing/td-p/3663790) (link goes to an HPE article) disables kernel correction for leap seconds and thus lets the ordinary NTP protocol to smooth over the one-second gain using the normal time synchronization mechanisms. See [Five different ways to handle leap seconds with NTP](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/06/01/five-different-ways-handle-leap-seconds-ntp/) for an in-depth discussion of ways of smoothing over leap seconds.